Problem importing packages from other Module - Spring Boot and Gradle
I'm currently working on implementing a modular monolith architecture using Spring Boot along with Gradle. Here's my folder structure:
enter image description here
Within each module, there's a build.gradle file. In the gateway module, where I import the project from the comments module to utilize external services, I do so in the following manner:
dependencies {
    implementation(project("modules:comments"))
}

However, I encountered an issue when attempting to use an external API in the gateway module:
package com.trycatch.comments_app.comments does not exist
import com.trycatch.comments_app.comments.CommentExternalAPI;

Here's the configuration of my root project with Gradle:
build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'com.trycatch'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springModulithVersion', "1.1.3")
    springBootVersion = '3.3.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-starter-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    implementation project('modules:comments')
    implementation project('modules:gateway')
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:3.2.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-bom:${springModulithVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

subprojects {
    group = rootProject.group
    version = rootProject.version

    apply plugin : 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            // use the same spring boot version as in the root
            mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
        }
    }

    // define dependencies every module will inherit
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:3.2.4'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
        implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2'
        implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}

settings.gradle:
rootProject.name = 'comments-app'
include 'modules:comments', 'modules:gateway'


Can anyone help me, is it an IDE or configuration problem?
I have made the configuration according to the documentation, I have also tried other import types for the modules, but nothing has worked
